# Docker compose doesn't copy files from custom image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a custom image created from my own project. The Dockerfile is quite simple:

```
from wordpress
COPY test.html /var/www/html
```

Using docker composer, if I run it using a volume, it's works fine.

```
wordpress:
    ...
    image: my_project_image
    volumes: ['volumetest:/var/www/html']
    ...
volumes:
  volumetest:
```

But if instead of creating a volume, if I map a local folder to the remote folder, the file test.html is not created, neither inside the wordpress container, neither inside the local folder:

```
wordpress:
    ...
    image: my_project_image
    volumes: ['./testdir:/var/www/html']
    ...
#volumes:
#  volumetest:
```

Is there a way I can create the file just by using the docker-compose?

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the build stage of the Docker image, you copy `test.html` to `/var/www/html` directory inside the Docker image.

When you run the image as a container, you map local `./testdir` to `/var/www/html` directory inside the container. This means `/var/www/html` now points to your `./testdir` directory. If your `./testdir` does not contain your `test.html` file, then you're not going to see it inside the container as well.

I believe you misunderstood that when you use volumes, it will copy the file in the image to the local file system. What happens is, whichever files you have in your local file system directory will reflect (you can think of this as replace as well) as the files in the mapped directory inside the container.

Comment: Hi Eranga, thanks for the answer. Maybe I misunderstood it. My ./testdir doesn't contains anything, but when I run the docker composer, all the files from the wordpress install are generated inside the ./testdir (like wp-content, php files), except for the test.html, that is not generated neither inside the container neither the local folder. Why it's ignores my test.html if the file is inside the image? And not ignore my file when I create a volume instead of mapping a folder?

Comment: The `volumes:` mount hides everything in the image and replaces it with the thing that's being mounted; what was in the image doesn't matter any more.  For named volumes there is a special case where, the first time a named volume is used, contents get copied from the container, but then if the image is updated, the volume takes priority; I would avoid relying on this feature.  As you've described the problem in your question you do not want `volumes:` at all.